# convert whole int number to percentage in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on a school project and I am pretty much done but have been stuck in a detail. I am asking the user to enter their starting balance and the interest rate, to make it easier for the user just asking to enter a whole number like 1, 2, 3, etc. Example, if they enter 1000 in starting balance and 9% in the interest rate the result would 1750.00, the expected result is 1007.50 which comes when the user enters .09%, is there a way to change any number the user enters to that so when they enter 9 it transforms it into .09. If you run the code, enter starting balance and rate and then select "M", you will see those numbers. Any ideas will be appreciated, here is the code:

```
///BankDemo class
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankDemo {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unlikely-arg-type")
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        float startingBalance;
        float interestRate;
        String userInput;
                
        System.out.print("Enter beginning balance :$");
        startingBalance = keyboard.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.print("Enter interest rate(whole number) :%");
        interestRate = keyboard.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.println("Enter D for deposit" + "\nEnter W to Withdraw" + "\nEnter B for Balance" + 
                            "\nEnter M for Monthly Process" + "\nEnter E to Exit");
        userInput = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
        
        float bal = startingBalance;
        float rate = interestRate;
        
        BankAccount ba = new BankAccount(startingBalance, interestRate);
        SavingsAccount sv = new SavingsAccount(bal, rate);
        
        if("d".equals(userInput)) {
            ba.deposit();
        } else if("w".equals(userInput)) {
            ba.withdraw();
        } else if("b".equals(userInput)) {
            ba.totalBalance();
        } else if("m".equals(userInput)) {
            ba.monthlyProcess();
        } else if("e".equals(userInput)) {
            ba.exit();
        } else {
            System.out.print("Error, option to valid");
        }
    }

}
///BankAccount Class

import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankAccount {
    protected float balance;
    protected float numDeposits;
    protected float numWithdrawals;
    protected float annualRate;
    protected float monthlyServCharg;
     
    public BankAccount() {
        balance = 0;
        numDeposits = 0;
        numWithdrawals = 0;
        annualRate = 0;
        monthlyServCharg = 0;
    }
    
    public BankAccount(float startingBalance, float interestRate) {
        balance = startingBalance;
        annualRate = interestRate;
    }
    public void deposit() {
        float valueD;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to deposit :$");
        valueD = keyboard.nextFloat();
        balance += valueD;
        numDeposits++;
    }
    public void withdraw() {
        float valueW;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to withdraw :$");
        valueW = keyboard.nextFloat();
        
        if(valueW < 1) {
            System.out.println("Error: Must enter positive value\n");
        }
        balance -= valueW;
        numDeposits++;
    }
    public void totalBalance() {
        System.out.print("Balance is: " + balance);
    }
    public void calcInterest() {
        float monRate = annualRate / 12;
        float monInt = balance * monRate;
        balance += monInt;
    }
    public void monthlyProcess() {
        calcInterest();
        balance -= monthlyServCharg;
        numWithdrawals = 0;
        numDeposits = 0;
        monthlyServCharg = 0;
        System.out.printf("Your Balance after Monthly process is: %.2f", balance);
    }
    
    public void exit() {
        totalBalance();
        System.out.print("\nThank you. Bye");
    }
}
```

Comment: well, 100% = 1 so why dont you just divide the given number like this: interestRate /= 100.0f;

Answer (score 1):

In your overload constructor, set annualRate equal to (interestRate / 100) to convert it to a percentage. Also, as a side node, you don't need to initialize all the variables on the default constructor because they're initialize to 0 since they're primitive data types.